# Normalized colormap distorted

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to normalise a colormap and came across [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330175/97137) answer on Stackexchange. It does exactly what I want. Or at least it did. However, the answer and the code are five years old and the code no longer fully reproduces the desired result.

What do I need to change in the code to get the result I want?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
import geopandas as gpd

# generate data
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf = gdf[gdf.continent == 'Africa']
gdf['random'] = np.random.gamma(2, 2, len(gdf)) - 2

# normalize color
vmin, vmax, vcenter = gdf.random.min(), gdf.random.max(), 0
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=vmin, vcenter=vcenter, vmax=vmax)
# create a normalized colorbar
cmap = 'RdBu'
cbar = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 7))
# with no normalization
gdf.plot(column='random', cmap=cmap, legend=True, ax=ax1)

# with normalization
gdf.plot(column='random', cmap=cmap, norm=norm, legend=False, ax=ax2)
# add colorbar
fig.colorbar(cbar, ax=ax2)
```

Today:
[image]

Desired solution:
[image]

Comment: See [github issue 22197](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22197).  The change seems to be very intended. The suggested solution to get the old behavior would be `ax2.set_yscale('linear')`. Could you confirm that your issue is with how the color bar is displayed, not with the colors? (Or could you do both tests with the same "random" values?)

Comment: Yes, the problem is with how the colour bar is displayed, not with the colours. The colour bar should look like in the lower right plot. `ax2.set_yscale('linear')` does not solve the problem.

Comment: To set the yscale of the last created colorbar: `fig.axes[-1].set_yscale('linear')`.  Or you could grab the colorbar when it is created: `cbar2 = fig.colorbar(cbar, ax=ax2)` and then `cbar2.ax.set_yscale('linear')`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It answers my question! :)